# General mathematics for confidence interval in multiple linear regression

Tags: confidence-interval, multiple-regression

I have 30 observations and 4 *(edited: numerical)* variables (x1, x2, x3, x4). Also I have a linear model to predict y value. I want to calculate confidence interval for predicted (*edited: and calculated*) y values. I know that confidence level in one-factor analysis can be calculated multiplying t-value and standard error. How it is done in multi-factor analysis? My pre-knowledge is that there is matrix calculations involved.

Comment: Are your X variables categorical? How many levels do they have? You probably don't have enough data to reasonably assess the relationships b/t these variables & Y.

Comment: x variables are numerical. the question is not about reasonability.

Comment: Your question should be more explicit about whether it's an interval for the *mean* or an interval for a future value.

Comment: if i am asking about confidence interval, then isnt it explicit enough defining what you are calling "interval for the mean"? No offence, I`m just asking.

Comment: anyways... now I would like to know the general mathematics for prediction interval as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of preserving the answers given in the link :
http://reliawiki.org/index.php/Multiple_Linear_Regression_Analysis#Confidence_Intervals_in_Multiple_Linear_Regression

Confidence Intervals in Multiple Linear Regression

1. ***Confidence Interval on β<sub>j</sub>***
   A 100 (1−α) percent confidence interval on the regression coefficient, βj, is obtained as follows:
   $${{\hat{\beta }}_{j}}\pm {{t}_{\alpha /2,n-(k+1)}}\sqrt{{{C}_{jj}}}\,\!$$

C<sub>jj</sub>  ⇒ diagonal elements of the matrix C
Matrix C ⇒ variance-covariance matrix of the estimated regression coefficients ${\hat{\beta}}s$
$$C={{\hat{\sigma }}^{2}}{{({{X}^{\prime }}X)}^{-1}}\,\!$$
The variances of the ${\hat{\beta}}s$ are obtained using the (X′X)<sup>-1</sup> matrix.
C is a symmetric matrix whose diagonal elements, C<sub>jj</sub>, represent the variance of the estimated jth regression coefficient, ${\hat{\beta}}_{j}$.
The off-diagonal elements, C<sub>ij</sub>, represent the covariance between the ith and jth estimated regression coefficients, ${\hat{\beta}}_{i}$ and ${\hat{\beta}}_{j}$.
The value of ${\hat{\sigma }}^{2}$ is obtained using the error mean square, MSE.


2) ***Confidence Interval on ${\hat{y }_{i}}$***
$${\hat{y }_{i}}\pm {{t}_{\alpha /2,n-(k+1)}} \sqrt{{{\hat{\sigma }}^{2}}{x'_{i}}{{({{X}^{\prime }}X)}^{-1}x_{i}}}\,\!$$
where
$$x_{i} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\x_{i1}\\.\\x_{ik} \end{bmatrix} $$


3) ***Confidence Interval on New Observations***
$${\hat{y }_{p}}\pm {{t}_{\alpha /2,n-(k+1)}} \sqrt{{{\hat{\sigma }}^{2}}(1 + {x'_{p}}{{({{X}^{\prime }}X)}^{-1}x_{p})}}\,\!$$
where
$$x_{p} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\x_{p1}\\.\\x_{pk} \end{bmatrix} $$
$x_{p1}, .. , x_{pk}$ ⇒ levels of the predictor variables for ${\hat{y }_{p}}$

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here -
http://reliawiki.org/index.php/Multiple_Linear_Regression_Analysis#Confidence_Intervals_in_Multiple_Linear_Regression - second formula in sub-chapter.

As i was asking for mathematics, i found the solution

[image]

capital X` is transposed array of Xes,

x` is i`th vector

Comment: how about giving theoretical basis for negative ratings, guys?

Comment: Welcome to this site! Would you mind summarizing the main points in your answer so that this thread remains self-contained?

Comment: @DidzisLauva - have a look at the other answers on the site to see the sort of thing that gets upvoted. Generally a link is not a good answer (if the link dies, the answer is useless).

Comment: ok, agree with those points. Will edit the answer ;)